# Failed to start puppetserver Service

Tags: service, puppet, ubuntu-server

While trying to run a puppet update form a node:

`sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t`

I get an error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppet" port 8140`
```

Elsewhere indicates this is likely a problem with the puppetserver service, and suggests to reboot the server.  Restarting didn't help, and when I try to restart the service I get failure:

```
~$ sudo service puppetserver restart
Job for puppetserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status puppetserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I've looked at these logs, and as a puppet/linux noob, I'm not sure what to do next.

## systemctl status puppetserver.service

```
● puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Fri 2016-09-02 15:54:26 PDT; 2s ago
  Process: 22301 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install --directory --owner=puppet --group=puppet --mode=775 /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver (code=exited
 Main PID: 22306 (java);         : 22307 (bash)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 335.7M
      CPU: 5.535s
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           ├─22306 /usr/bin/java -Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/p
           └─control
             ├─22307 /bin/bash /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/ezbake-functions.sh wait_for_app
             └─22331 sleep 1

Sep 02 15:54:26 puppet systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...
Sep 02 15:54:26 puppet java[22306]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

puppet version 4.6.1

Comment: what about `journalctl -xe`? That would be more helpful than the status message.

Comment: The systemctl status output is 2 seconds after the puppetserver start. Please wait a bit and then report the output. The server is still starting, and the output ist not usable.

Answer (score 1):

The puppet master communicates with the other node using port number 8140.
I don't think a restart will help, since this looks like a connection issue between the server and the node.
please try the following -

1. first make sure that the puppet master is actually listening on port 8140. run the following command on the puppetmaster - 
   `netstat -ntlp | grep 8140`

this command should return something like this -

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8140            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1783/puppetmaster
```

If you don't get the same output, your puppetmaster is not listening, and therefore can not compile catalogs for the node.
Try checking the puppet master log at `/var/log/puppetmaster.log`

2. check that the node can communicate with the puppetmaster on the relevant port. you can check this quickly with the `telnet` command. run this on your node -

   telnet < puppetmaster ip address \ dns name> 8140

you should get something like -

```
Connected to <puppet-master-IP/DNS-name>
Escape character is '^]'.
```

if you don't get this output, this means that something is blocking you from accessing the puppetmaster. try opening the port in your firewall to access the puppetmaster.

3. if you're still stuck try using the --debug flag for verbose output and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Could be 2 things:  (1) in puppet.conf you have configured more memory than you have on your machine.  Or (2) You installed both apt-get install puppetserver and apt-get install puppet.

Answer (score 0):

If you get failed to start puppet.service: unit not found. error on slave machine while connecting to puppet.
Close the putty and then again open and connect it.The issue wont come while starting putty on slave.

Comment: It is perhaps worth recognizing that the question you have answered is nearly four years old.  The OP is unlikely to still be paying attention to it, to be able to meaningfully comment on it, or to answer any questions about it.  It is sometimes useful to answer old questions, but for the most part, your insights will be most valuable if you apply them to new questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because there is not enough RAM and to fix the error, open the Puppet server configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver
```

And reduce the amount of allocated RAM for the Puppet server (for example, I specified 512m instead of 2g):

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

Now let’s start the Puppet server:

```
sudo systemctl start puppetserver
```